# Setting a profile for firefox Error: Unable to convert capabilities

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

To add an extension to firefox i tried the code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");    
String path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi";
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(new File(path));            
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Firefox you are using?

Comment: @RNS Version 53.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for creating Firefox Profile and correct property path for geckodriver:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(false);
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have observed in your code that you are using `geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64`.

This issue is fixed in the latest version of geckodriver.

You can download latest geckodriver from following link:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The name of the extension you are trying to use `{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi` is of **Firebug**.

Question for you: **`Is your extension signed?`**  The Answer is "No".

So according to [MDN](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing), **"Firefox 48: (Pushed from Firefox 46). Release and Beta versions of Firefox for Desktop will not allow unsigned extensions to be installed, with no override.**

So to install an unsigned extension you'll need to downgrade firefox to 47.x versions.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.